# One-shot learning with scikit-learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Say I have only 1 positive to train a classifier. Is there any way to train a model with scikit-learn with only one positive? (e.g. similar to exemplar SVM).

At the moment I have the following:

```
scores = [
   ('precision', precision_score),
]

for score_name, score_func in scores:
    clf = GridSearchCV(SVC(C=1), tuned_parameters, score_func=score_func)
    clf.fit(X[train], y[train])
    y_true, y_pred = y[test], clf.predict(X[test])
```

But I get the following error:

> ValueError: The least populated class in y has only 2 members, which
>   is too few. The minimum number of labels for any class cannot be less
>   than k=3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no model dedicated to one shot learning in scikit-learn.

Furthermore as you should see in the full traceback of your error message, `GridSearchCV` is using cross validation internally so you cannot use it a on dataset that does not have at least 2 positive samples.